# Using promise chaining in resolve feature of $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngroute

One of my variables in resolve method has dependency of another variable, is it possible to share same promise among variables in resolve method?

It seems $route.current.locals stores the resolved variables, however when var2 is processed, $route.current.locals is null since var1 is not resolved yet. What I'm trying to is something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/report/:ruleId', { resolve: {
    var1: ['$route', 'service', function ($route, service) {
        return service.getRequest();
    }],
    var2: ['$route', 'service', function ($route, service) {
        return service.getAnotherRequest($route.current.locals.var1.id);
    }]
}});
```

Comment: You need to use $q.all [See the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and put the results in an object {var1: value, var2: value}

Comment: somePromise is created in the scope of var1, and var2 uses the resolved data of somePromise. I updated the code.

Comment: Oh then use .then().  (Also this should all be done in the service)

Comment: If you mean "can I wait var1 resolving before calling var2" => not possible with your syntax. You'll have to manually call both in a single resolve.

Comment: It would be really nice if this were supported!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will work:

```
$routeProvider.when('/report/:ruleId', { resolve: {
    vars: ['$route', 'service','$q' function ($route, service) {
        var defer = $q.defer(),
        data = [];
        service.getRequest().then(function(firstResponse){
            data.push(firstResponse);
            service.getAnotherRequest(firstResponse.id).then(function(secondResponse){
                data.push(secondResponse);
                defer.resolve(data);
            });
        })

        return defer.promise;

    }],

}});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option in this case is not exactly promise chaining, more promise nesting.  This changes the output, but not significantly:

```
$routeProvider.when('/report/:ruleId', { resolve: {
    bothVars: ['$route', '$service', function ($route, $service) {
        return $service.getRequest().
        then(function(response1) {
            return $service.getAnotherRequest(response1.data.id).
            then(function(response2) {
                return {
                    var1: response1.data,
                    var2: response2.data
                };
            });
        });
    ]
}});
```

This can get a little wild if you nest too deeply, but I think this is fine.  I don't love this solution, but it's the best I've found for this particular problem.  One final note: don't preface your own services with '$'.  Angular uses that convention for it's own services to avoid conflicts.

Comment: It occurred to me after posting this that if you have control of your service endpoints (the API), then the best overall solution might be to return all of the data that you need from the same request if possible.

Comment: This can be solution but it would be nice if we could do it. This way is much more messy I think.